# how to sequentially read two txt files and write into a new file in python?

Tags: python

I have two txt files,  with 100000 lines for each file, now I need to generate a new file which combines the content from previous two txt files in such a way that,  every 32 lines in the first file and every 64 lines in the second file are extracted and then write into the new file, so on and so on until all the lines in the both files are writen into the new file.

How would I do it in python, I know the way of reading all the lines in one file and write them into another.

```
with open(app_path+'/empty.txt','r') as source:
    data = [  (random.random(), line) for line in source ]
    data.sort()
with open(app_path+'/empty2.txt','w') as target:
    for _,line in data:
        target.write( line )
```

but for reading 2 files, extracting the content and writing sequentially, I have no idea

Comment: 32 and 64? You're going to run out of lines in one file while having half the other file still to go, then what? And why does your title say 'sequentially' but your example code randomises the order?

Comment: The example code is just now I know how to read one file and write another, don't worry about the sort. What I mean sequentially is new file will fill 32 lines read from first file and then 64 lines from second file, so on until the first file is done, then write all the rest from second file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per TessellatingHeckler, you will run out of file 2 first. This method will then continue to write from the remaining file until done.

```
from itertools import islice
with open('target.txt', 'w') as target:
    f1, f2 = open('f1.txt'), open('f2.txt')
    while True:
        ls1 = islice(f1, 32)
        if not ls1:
            # will not happen in this case
            target.write('\n' + f2.read())
            break
        ls2 = islice(f2, 64)
        if not ls2:
            target.write('\n' + f1.read())
            break
        target.write('\n'.join('\n'.join(ls) for ls in [ls1, ls2]))
    f1.close()
    f2.close()
```

Comment: May I ask why you use the proper "with open()" then use the old plain open?

Comment: Mostly because I felt that this would be more readable without nested indents. But also this can be extended to a case where one has to merge more than two files.